# Why does no non-trivial reduced words in $H_1 \backslash \{e\} \sqcup H_2 \backslash \{e\}$ imply that $\left< H_1, H_2 \right> = H_1 \ast H_2$?

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory, free-product

I am currently studying combinatorial group theory and am trying to prove the ping pong lemma. Many of the proofs I have come across seem to use a result of the following flavour.

Let $G$ be a group and $H_1,H_2 \leq G$ if every reduced word in $H_1 \backslash\{e\}\sqcup H_2 \backslash \{e\}$ is non-trivial, then $\left<H_1,H_2\right>=H_1 \ast H_2$ the free product.
How would one go about proving this? I am currently attempting to use the universal property of free products.

Let $K$ be a group and $\varphi_1:H_1 \to K$ and $\varphi_2: H_2 \to K$ be homomorphisms then I have
recursively defined the map $\varphi: \left<H_1,H_2\right> \to K$ by
$$
 g_0\ldots g_n \mapsto
 \begin{cases}
  \varphi_1(g_0) &\text{if $n=0$ and $g_0 \in H_1$}\\
  \varphi_2(g_0) &\text{if $n=0$ and $g_0 \in H_2$}\\
  \varphi_1(g_0)\varphi(g_1\ldots g_n) &\text{if $g_0 \in H_1$}\\
  \varphi_2(g_0)\varphi(g_1\ldots g_n) &\text{if $g_0 \in H_2$}
 \end{cases}
$$
Showing that this map preserves structure seems simple enough but how do I prove that it is well defined. My gut is telling me that it is here that the assumption that no reduced word is trivial comes into play but I do not know how to proceed. My intention is to continue by showing that $\varphi_1 = \varphi\circ\iota_{1}$ where $\iota:H_1 \to \left<H_1,H_2\right>$ is the inclusion map etc. hence $\varphi$ satisfies the universal property and $\left< H_1,H_2\right> = H_1 \ast H_2$.

I have a tendency of becoming entangled in the details and missing obvious results, especially when it comes to showing maps are well defined so I apologise if that is the case and appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: The hypothesis implies that every element of $\langle H_1,H_2 \rangle$ can be written as unique product of the form $g_1g_2 \cdots g_n$ in which each $g_i$ lies in $H_1 \cup H_2$ and, for all $i<n$, we do not have $g_i,g_{i+1} \in H_1$ or $g_i,g_{i+1} \in H_2$. That will enable you to well-define your map $\varphi$. You would then have to continue the arguments.

Comment: From the universal property of $H_1*H_2$, you get a morphism into $G$; the fact that no reduced word is trivial tells you the map is injective, and hence its image, which is the subgroup generated by $H_1$ and $H_2$, is isomorphic to $H_1*H_2$.